# jQuery .show() and other transitions do not fully complete making the user think "nothing happened"

Tags: jquery

I have had a problem for a while now where different elements on my webapp that are revealed by `.show()` do not completely show.  There are quite a few calls on different objects to `.show()` and some will complete just fine on the page.

Here is one example of the issue:

1) The page has a section with the ID of "`showMore_2`":

```
<div id="showMore_2" class="showMore clear">
```

2) Now click the button to show the object and I get this:

```
<div id="showMore_2" class="showMore clear" style="overflow: hidden; height: 1px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 1px; opacity: 0;">
```

Technically it now invisible (`opacity: 0`) and is gets stuck with a height of 1px and the user thinks "nothing happened" so they keep clicking and nothing continues to happen. The opacity does not continue to increase and the height does not continue to increase like it does when all goes well.

I feel like I am missing a fundamental concept here, but what, I don't know.

Comment: Can you post the jquery/javascript or make a fiddle? It is difficult for us to help answer a JS question when we cant see the JS!

Comment: You should post a minimal HTML, CSS and JS that reproduces the issue - in order to get some proper help on that one. P.S: funny that people usually and interestingly while creating that *minimal* example code - realize pretty fast what the issue actually was :D

Comment: I do not get this to occur every time.  It is random.  Sometimes it works perfect for days and then one click and it gets stuck.  I wonder if this is affected by other .show() and .hide() calls on the page on different elements and they queue up or something.   If I make just the snippet and test it alone, it never fails - it always shows.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have initial values set to one of your classes.

> class="showMore clear"

I mean, one of your classes, both or even your tag's id together give you the result you see and exactly the behavior it is supposed to have with a 1px height and a "0" opacity, once the only change .show() function is applying to your selected tag is to set your "Display" property to "block", as you can see in JQuery doc:

> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block"),
>   except that the display property is restored to whatever it was
>   initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden
>   and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

So apparently your code is working, your Div is there waiting for something else, like changing its height and opacity or removing the class that defines the unwanted behavior.

I suggest you to test the .show() function by adding this after its call:

```js
$("#showMore_2").removeClass("showMore clear")
```

Comment: I may not have explained myself in the beast way.  This code works fine 99% of the time and then sometimes this element or other ones just freeze on a partial expand.  if I refresh the page and click the element that triggers the .show(), then it will work.   I wonder if somehow there are so many /show() and .hide() events on the page that somehow it gets lost in some queue I do not know about.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code in a console? You can add breakpoints to your code, then try to replicate your problem.

Comment: Yes.  The tough part is that 99.99% of the time it works and the time that it does not, the debugger continues as though it does.